What's wrong on this attempt to custom Thumb color of a WPF ScrollBar?
Here's my basic style for a ScrollViewer component in WPF:
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}"
       x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Orientation"
                 Value="Horizontal">
            <Setter Property="Height"
                    Value="6" />
            <Setter Property="MinHeight"
                    Value="6" />
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="#ddeffb" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Orientation"
                 Value="Vertical">
            <Setter Property="Width"
                    Value="10" />
            <Setter Property="MinWidth"
                    Value="10" />
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="#ddeffb" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

It changes the background of the scroll bar, which is ok.
Now, I'd like to also change the color of Thumb. Tried adding this after </Style.Triggers>, but nothing happens:
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="#4a90e2" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="#3a78c2" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                    Value="1" />
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>


Is there any other properties I need to deal with?
Here's the XML:
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              Padding="0"
              Margin="0">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <GroupBox x:Name="MyGroupTitle"
                  Width="Auto"
                  Height="Auto"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Margin="30,30,30,0">
            <Grid Margin="0,20,20,20"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top">
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>


It works only if the Style of an element is not explicitly set. And it is not the case for ScrollBar's Thumb. You can find the default Style by Edit Template and Edit a copy in Document Outline digging ScrollViewer, ScrollBar and Track and edit it.

So once I find, what should I do?

Edit the Style as you wish.

I don't follow you. I'm editing the Style, but I don't know, on which properties?
